# Не видит HttpUtility

Tags: c#

Выходит ошибка :

*Элемент "HttpUtility" не существует в текущем контексте*

Что делать не пойму!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если и после добавления ссылки на System.Web не видит - поставьте в свойствах проекта Target Framework на полный .NET (не Client Profile).

Comment: ... если и после этого не заработает, проверьте версию .NET, должна быть >= 1.1. Если и после этого не заработает, проверьте, компилируете ли вы проект на C# или на нативном C++. Если и после этого не заработает, ...

Answer (score 2):

Информации слишком мало. В качестве догадки: добавьте в ссылки проекта сборку System.Web.

Answer (score 1):

В качестве ещё одной догадки, проверьте наличие

```
using System.Web;
```

во том файле, который не компилируется.